# Codeigniter update a column in a database while retrieving with activerecords

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I'am learning to make a blog in CodeIgniter 2.x . What I want - when user clicks on the link **readmore** on the blog's page, it will redirect him to the page with corresponding `id` to show him a full article.

Now, while retrieving a `$query->row();` from a database in `content_model.php`, i want to update a `viewed` column in database at the same time. So instead of showing him for example `34 views`, it will show `35 views`, and when someone open the same link it will shows him by one more - `36 views`.

What's the best way to do it without making it vulnerable to hackers somehow ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieving data from database using CI framework, you check this following:

```
    if ($result_from_get_function->num_rows()>0){
    return   $this->updateViewColoumnByOne();
    }else{
    return false;
    }
    function updateViewColoumnByOne(){
    //retrieve number of view in view column, suppose 12.
    //plus one with it; 12+1=13
   //update it.
   //again retrieve the new update number of views
   //and return.
   }
```

I think this could help you.

Comment: that's what i tried to did, i will update my question to show you my code

Comment: your post table (where full article has) contains number_of_views column, if so, would you please make a another table for number of views which foreign key is post_table_id. and be sure type in mysql table.

Answer (score 1):

This should be very easy. When someone tries to read a post, just before you retrieve the post information, update the count views in the database. Execute a query that goes something like this

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `views` = `views` + 1;
```

After that, simply retrieve the post information just like you normally would, and then show it to the user by outputting it to the browser.

Comment: i tried it, but something is wrong, it updates all that column to 'zero' everytime. I'am using `activerecords` instead of `sql` directly.

Comment: Well, you need to be specific in the query. The query I posted above is just a general idea of what you should do. To actually make it work, you have to add a where clause so that the code updates only the row that it needs to update.